# can unetbootin create UEFI bootable rescue disk on USB?

Tags: windows, gpt, uefi, malware

How do I run unetbootin **from a non-UEFI system** so that the **Kaspersky** rescue disk on USB it creates will work under UEFI boot for **Windows 10**?  I don't want alter the boot configuration on the windows laptop.

Some software will format the USB flash thumb drive for UEFI boot, but I'm not seeing this option for unetbootin.  The system I'm running uses regular old BIOS, but the pen drive will be used on an UEFI system.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can replace it with [SystemRescue LiveCD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/) when you wanted rescue Linux OS.

Your BIOS can't support UEFI boot. Or you can find Kaspersky Rescue with normal boot without UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need any kind of UEFI on a system used to create a UEFI-capable image/stick; you only need to arrange a specific filesystem layout there (with EFI/ directory holding EFI-capable bootloader).

[Rod's EFI guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) might be a good start on the topic, and if a generic rescue image is what you actually need than I'd both second SRCD proposal in the first answer and suggest my own [ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) which is capable of booting with UEFI and usually doesn't even need to disable "Secure Boot".